# How to obtain only important timezones and their UTC offset from moment-timezone rather than all 596 timezones?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset, moment-timezone

I am using the `moment-timezone` to obtain the zones and their respective UTC offset within the `Nuxt 3` application. Everything is working as expected but the library returns me with 596 timezones which I feel is too much to use within the application as I am using these timezones to populate the Select dropdown field.

Is there a way I can get only important timezones rather than all the timezones? Because I see that there are few duplication of the timezone offset so I tried to remove the duplications but this makes some of the timezone names to miss out:

Following is the approach I am using:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
const timezones = ref([]);

const getTimezonesWithOffset = () => {
  const zones = moment.tz.names();
  let offsetTmz = [];

  for (let i in zones) {
    const offset = `(GMT${moment.tz(zones[i]).format("Z")})`;
    const offsetObj = { text: zones[i], value: offset };
    offsetTmz.push(offsetObj);
  }

  timezones.value = offsetTmz.sort();
};

onMounted(async () => {
  await getTimezonesWithOffset();
  console.log(timezones.value.length);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(timezones.value, null, 4));
});
```

I tried to filter for unique offset:

```
if (!uniqueOffsets.has(offset)) {
        uniqueOffsets.add(offset);
        formattedTimezones.push(`${zone} - ${offset}`);
      }
```

But using this approach will miss out on some of the zone names but able to get unique UTC offset. I would like to know if there is a way to obtain only the most used or important timezones rather than all the zones using the `moment-timezone` library or is there any better library which i can use for getting only important zones.

Comment: The current offset does not properly disambiguate timezones.

Comment: @Bergi I do not understand what you mean. Are you saying the calculation of the offset is wrong or something? Here: `const offset = (GMT${moment.tz(zones[i]).format("Z")})`

Comment: I mean that there are multiple distinct timezones (with different rules) that may currently observe the same utc offset. Your deduplication approach won't work.

Comment: Instead of removing potentially useful timezones, try to think if there's a better UI for this that's not a giant dropdown. Just storing offsets is definitely wrong because different timezones have different rules for things like daylight savings time.

Comment: This has been done a variety of different ways by many different projects.  However none of them are simple enough to give a StackOverflow answer for.  The key point is - how does one decide which time zones are "important".  That will change drastically depending on your business requirements and worldview.  The tzdb makes no such assumptions.  All time zones are important, because all use cases are important to _someone_.

Comment: As a bad example of how not to do it - Rails (the Ruby framework) decided originally to filter the tzdb list to a "meaningful subset" of zones and rename them for "simplicity".  The result was bug report after bug report of "what about me?", "me too!" etc.  Not to mention that elimination of historical zones means anyone with past-data-analysis use cases was completely screwed.

Comment: The question I have for you is: What is the use case for picking the time zone?  You say the user is picking "their" time zone - if that's all you need, why do you need a picker at all?  You can just get their time zone with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`.  On the other hand, you might be picking a time zone for somewhere else - such as a meeting location, etc.  Can you elaborate on the use case please?